# AUTOSAR Multiplicity * means 0 .. n or 1 .. n?

Tags: autosar

AUTOSAR Multiplicity * means 0 .. n or 1 .. n?
That means, does * means the corresponding attribute can be optional also or it is a must attribute?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of "*" is 0..n. In this specific case the corresponding association in the UML diagram also shows the multiplicity "*". But in many other case where the multiplicity "*" is shown in the class table, the UML diagram shows 0..*.